# how to run two python scripts parallelly using shell script and save their return value in a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have two python scripts and I have to run them parallelly at the same time and store their retun value in a variable. Could you please help me how to do this?

Example:

`script1.py` and `script2.py`

`x` is variable to store script1.py return value

`y` is variable to store script2.py return value

both the scripts are returning either 0/1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the process on the background using `&` operator. Then you have to wait for all the background processes using `wait`. This command also provides return code of the awaited process.

Quick and dirty example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# first command to be executed
sleep 3 &
pid1=$!

# second command to be executed
sleep 5 &
pid2=$!

wait $pid1
x=$?

wait $pid2
y=$?

echo "x: $x, y: $y"
```

Comment: but where is the script name in your shell script?

Comment: example uses sleep command. You can change `sleep X &` to `python whatever.py &`. Just don't forget the `&` operator.

Comment: not working sir